# Matching a string against multiple patterns

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a  question regarding the style of a solution for a pretty simple problem.

I have a program that matches a list of file names against a number of patterns. If the file name matches a pattern, the file is renamed and a counter is incremented.

Currently I'm matching against 4 different patterns like this

```
if ([file rangeOfString:pattern].location != NSNotFound) {
counter ++;
//rename file...
}

if ([file rangeOfString:pattern2].location != NSNotFound) {
counter2 ++;
//rename file...
}
[...]
```

The solution works well but does not scale. If I have to match against significantly more patterns.

So I thought about using something like

```
NSString *someRegexp = ...; 
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:file, someRegexp]; 

if ([myTest evaluateWithObject: testString]){

}
```

However, I do not see any way to increment the counters in such a solution as they depend on the exact match....

So I was wondering whether anybody here knows a more comprehensive/nice solution for this problem.....

Thanks in advance
Norbert

Comment: how about putting the patterns in an array and having the file loop through them?

Comment: That was one of my considered solutions. However, I'd also have to put the counters into the array. It would end up in an array of structs/objects.....
My initial thought about that solution was: too complex :-(
Specifically, the initial complexity is pretty high so that for my 4 patterns to match, there would most likely even be more code...

Comment: you mean you want a unique counter for every pattern?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the counters for statistics and there has to be one counter per pattern...,

Comment: check out my answer. it makes things easy to do it that way.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best way (even though I have to admit that I'm not 100% with it.....)

Comment: this is where programmer's creativity comes in. There are several ways to do it. If you don't want to create extra files, you could use a dictionary. With keys being the patterns and values being the count, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about subclassing NSString, adding a counter to track the `match count`.

```
@interface PatternMatchingString : NSString

@property (readwrite) NSUInteger matchCount;

@end

-(void)patternMatching
{
    for(PatternMatchingString *pattern in arrayOfPatterns)
    {
        if([file rangeOfString:pattern].location != NSNotFound)
            pattern.matchCount++;
    }
}
```